# JavaFX/Mac: System menu becomes unresponsive when I set useSystemMenuBar to true

Tags: java, macos, javafx

I'm writing a JavaFX app and I'd like to have a better integration with the Mac, so I tried to set useSystemMenuBar=true on the main Stage menuBar.
What happens is that the menu is actually moved to the mac system menu, but it is totally unresponsive, nothing happens when I click on it.

I tried the [examples in NSMenuFX](https://github.com/0x4a616e/NSMenuFX/tree/master/src/test/java/de/codecentric/centerdevice/sample) and they exhibit exactly the same behaviour...

Any idea?

Details: Oracle Java 8, macOS Catalina 10.15.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug. Have a look here:
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8233678

Comment: Thanks, I should have checked bug reports first... I assume you are the latest commenter on the bug report?
So the only workaround you know of is to use NSMenuFX with jpackage? That's not good news for me as I'm stuck with Java 8...

Comment: Maybe that is motivation enough to upgrade :-)

Comment: I'm motivated but one of the libraries that i'm using is not :(